# Test for correlated vs uncorrelated increments in random walks

Tags: probability, hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, stochastic-processes, random-walk

Is there a test that can distinguish the strictest form of the random walk,

$$P_{t}=P_{t-1}+\varepsilon_{t}, \varepsilon_{t} \sim \mathrm{IID}\left(0, \sigma^{2}\right)$$

where each step is assumed to be ***identical*** and independently distributed, from the most general form of the random walk,

$$Cov(\varepsilon_{t}, \varepsilon_{t-k} ) = 0, k \neq 0$$

where each step ***may not be identical***?

I realize that for uncorrelated increments, all of the autocorrelations of the increments are zero, but I'm having difficulty establishing a "threshold" above which I can confidently say that my random walk has *identical* increments.

Comment: You mean you want to test the i.i.d. null hypothesis under the maintained hypothesis of no serial correlation, for the first-differenced series.

Comment: Yes, the alternate would be the i.i.d. hypothesis, the null will be the no serial correlation.

Comment: "...the alternate would be the i.i.d. hypothesis, the null will be the no serial correlation..."---how can the alternative be a subset of the null?

Comment: I see your point. I will reformulate my problem, thank you.